# clearInterval() function is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, timeout, clearinterval

i tried to add a simple random number generater upto 10. When code is excecuted its working fine and generating random numbers. after that i added a condition that when function generate 5 random number function should stop working, So I added clearInterval() function but there is no change in output.

```js
var stop = setInterval(timer, 1000);
var t = 0;

function timer() {
   var count = 0;
   var X = document.getElementById("timer");
   var rnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
   X.innerHTML = rnumber;
   
   count++;
   if (count == 5) {
     clearInterval(stop);
   }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="timer">0</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Move `var count = 0;` outside function. You are setting it to `0` every time.

Comment: your count is always 0, it doesn't count up in your function. as rayon said, move the count outside of your function. Easiest way to find the issue would be a console.log before you increase your count. console.log(count). than you can see, it is always 0.

Comment: `count` is set to zero whenever `timer` executes - see the first line of timer function.  You could declare `count` outside the function like you do for `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting count to 0 every time. Here's how to do it

```
function timer() {
   if (!this.count) this.count = 0;
   var X = document.getElementById("timer");
   var rnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
   X.innerHTML = rnumber;

   this.count++;
   if (this.count == 5) {
     clearInterval(stop);
   }
}
```

```js
    var stop = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    
    function timer() {
       console.log("running");
       if (!this.count) this.count = 0;
       var X = document.getElementById("timer");
       var rnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
       X.innerHTML = rnumber;
    
       this.count++;
       if (this.count == 5) {
         clearInterval(stop);
         console.log("stopped");
       }
    }
```

```html
<div id="timer">a</div>
```

Comment: he is not resetting his count, he is always redeclaring it to 0 in his local variable. Maybe post a working example within a code tag containing some console.log, so you can directly see the output